# Call parallel_apply for batch of rows

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, pandarallel

I need to apply a function on df, I used a `pandarallel` to parallelize the process, however, I have an issue here, I need to give `func_do` an N rows each call so that I can utilize a vectorization on that function.

The following will call `func_do` on each row. Any idea how to make a single call for each batch and keep the parallelization process.

```
def fun_do(value_col):
    return do(value_col)
df['processed_col'] = df.parallel_apply(lambda row: fun_do(row['col']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create virtual groups of N rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandarallel import pandarallel

# Setup MRE
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=False)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.linspace(0, 100, 11)})

def fun_do(sr):
    return sr**2
N = 4  # size of chunk
df['col2'] = (df.groupby(pd.RangeIndex(len(df)) // N)
                .parallel_apply(lambda x: fun_do(x['col1']))
                .droplevel(0))  # <- remove virtual group index
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     col1     col2
0     0.0      0.0
1    10.0    100.0
2    20.0    400.0
3    30.0    900.0
4    40.0   1600.0
5    50.0   2500.0
6    60.0   3600.0
7    70.0   4900.0
8    80.0   6400.0
9    90.0   8100.0
10  100.0  10000.0
```

**Note**: I don't know why `groupby(...)['col'].parallel_apply(fun_do)` doesn't work. It seems `parallel_apply` is not available with `SeriesGroupBy`.
This is the first time I use `pandarallel`, usually I [used `multiprocessing` module](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A15239951%20multiprocess)