# labeling segments of cyclical data based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is a follow-up on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77842667/labeling-segments-of-data-based-on-multiple-conditions) I posted that a member graciously provided the solution for. However, I had neglected to account for periodicity in my question.

I have a dataframe like so:

```
data = {'ID':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'column1': [15, 16, 17, 14, 13, 5, 3, 2, 1.9, 1.2, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'column2': [10, 11, 12, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
    }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

    
    ID  column1  column2
0    1     15.0     10.0
1    1     16.0     11.0
2    1     17.0     12.0
3    1     14.0     13.0
4    1     13.0     13.5
5    1      5.0     14.0
6    1      3.0     14.5
7    1      2.0     15.0
8    1      1.9     16.0
9    1      1.2     17.0
10   1      1.0     18.0
11   1      0.8     19.0
12   1      0.5     20.0
13   1      0.5     20.0
14   1      0.5     20.0
15   1      0.5     20.0
16   1      0.5     20.0
17   1      0.5     19.0
18   1      0.5     18.0
19   1      0.5     17.0
20   1      0.5     16.0
21   1      1.0     15.0
22   1      2.0     14.0
23   1      3.0     13.0
24   1      4.0     12.0
25   1      5.0     11.0
26   1      6.0     10.0
```

As can be seen, column`1` decreases and then increases. Column `2` increases and then decreases.
I want to create a label column based on the following conditions:

1. In `column1`, from the beginning until just before we first encounter a
   value `<=2`, **AND** when `column2` is `>13`, label as `Pre_Start`
2. When column 1 is decreasing **AND** `0.5 < column1 <= 2` **AND** column 2 is increasing **AND** `< column2 <= 19` label as `Start`
3. When `column1 <= 0.5` **AND** `column2 >= 19` label as `Steady`
4. When `column1 <= 0.5` **AND** column 2 is decreasing **AND** `14 < column2 < 19` label as `Ramp`
5. When column 1 is increasing **AND** `column1 > 0.5` **AND** column 2 is decreasing **AND** `column2 < 19` label as `End`

Im not sure if there is an ironclad boolean logic that would account for the conditions without looking at whether it is increasing or decreasing.

Using the method member Corralien provided, based on my question without addressing periodicity, I was able to get the resulting dataframe:

```
def label_group(df):
    c1 = df['column1']
    c2 = df['column2']
    conds = [(0.5 < c1) & (c1 <= 2) & (c2 > 14) & (c2 <= 19),  # Start
             (c1 <= 0.5) & (c2 >= 19),  # Steady
             (c1 <= 0.5) & (14 < c2) & (c2 < 19),  # Ramp
             (c1 > 0.5) & (c2 < 19)]  # End
    choices = ['Start', 'Steady', 'Ramp', 'End']

    labels = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices)
    labels = pd.Series(labels, index=df.index)
    labels[:((c1 <= 2) & (c2 > 13)).argmax()] = 'Pre_Start'

    return labels.to_frame()
    
df['Label'] = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=True).apply(label_group).droplevel('ID')

ID  column1  column2      Label
0    1     15.0     10.0  Pre_Start
1    1     16.0     11.0  Pre_Start
2    1     17.0     12.0  Pre_Start
3    1     14.0     13.0  Pre_Start
4    1     13.0     13.5  Pre_Start
5    1      5.0     14.0  Pre_Start
6    1      3.0     14.5  Pre_Start
7    1      2.0     15.0      Start
8    1      1.9     16.0      Start
9    1      1.2     17.0      Start
10   1      1.0     18.0      Start
11   1      0.8     19.0      Start
12   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
13   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
14   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
15   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
16   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
17   1      0.5     19.0     Steady
18   1      0.5     18.0       Ramp
19   1      0.5     17.0       Ramp
20   1      0.5     16.0       Ramp
21   1      1.0     15.0      Start
22   1      2.0     14.0        End
23   1      3.0     13.0        End
24   1      4.0     12.0        End
25   1      5.0     11.0        End
26   1      6.0     10.0        End
```

As can be seen, row 21 satisfies the `start` condition, however. It should be labeled `End` and state not satisfying any of the conditions labeled `other`.
I tried using the `shift()` function but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the same ID, can it have another cycle (from End to (Pre_)Start)? Are all phases necessarily present in a cycle (are there any missing phases)? (sorry for my incomplete previous answer)

Comment: @Corralien No, there wont be another cycle after End. There might be some phases that are not captured by the conditions which i believe can be bucketed using the `default` argument in the `np.select`clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your new conditions, you can use:

```
def label_group(df):
    c1 = df['column1']
    c2 = df['column2']
    i1 = c1.diff().shift(-1, fill_value=0).ge(0)  # is Increasing, column 1
    d2 = c2.diff().shift(-1, fill_value=0).le(0)  # is Decreasing, column 2
  
    conds = [~i1 & (0.5 < c1) & (c1 <= 2) & ~d2 & (c2 > 14) & (c2 <= 19),  # Start
             (c1 <= 0.5) & (c2 >= 19),  # Steady
             (c1 <= 0.5) & d2 & (14 < c2) & (c2 < 19),  # Ramp
             i1 & (c1 > 0.5) & d2 & (c2 < 19)]  # End
    choices = ['Start', 'Steady', 'Ramp', 'End']

    labels = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices)
    labels = pd.Series(labels, index=df.index)
    labels[:((c1 <= 2) & (c2 > 13)).argmax()] = 'Pre_Start'

    return labels.to_frame()

df['Label'] = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=True).apply(label_group).droplevel('ID')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID  column1  column2      Label
0    1     15.0     10.0  Pre_Start
1    1     16.0     11.0  Pre_Start
2    1     17.0     12.0  Pre_Start
3    1     14.0     13.0  Pre_Start
4    1     13.0     13.5  Pre_Start
5    1      5.0     14.0  Pre_Start
6    1      3.0     14.5  Pre_Start
7    1      2.0     15.0      Start
8    1      1.9     16.0      Start
9    1      1.2     17.0      Start
10   1      1.0     18.0      Start
11   1      0.8     19.0      Start
12   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
13   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
14   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
15   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
16   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
17   1      0.5     19.0     Steady
18   1      0.5     18.0       Ramp
19   1      0.5     17.0       Ramp
20   1      0.5     16.0       Ramp
21   1      1.0     15.0        End
22   1      2.0     14.0        End
23   1      3.0     13.0        End
24   1      4.0     12.0        End
25   1      5.0     11.0        End
26   1      6.0     10.0        End
```

Comment: Thank you! the solution is genius!  it works perfectly on small datasets, but it seems that using the `shift()` function on very large datasets is costly. Looks like I will have to find a different way to filter.

Comment: @thentangler. You can easily parallelize your `groupby_apply`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72846624/15239951) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566116/15239951). You can also use `Modin`